# Flutter HEALTH package get steps from user returns always null?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, google-fit

I am working on a personal project and I am using flutter to develop an app (cross platform) that reads in the user's health data from google fit (Android) or Apple Health.  [I am using this package](https://pub.dev/packages/health) and even the EXACT same code like in the documentation (I am currently only testing on Android):

```
Future fetchStepData() async {
    int? steps;

    // get steps for today (i.e., since midnight)
    final now = DateTime.now();
    final midnight = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day);

    bool requested = await health.requestAuthorization([HealthDataType.STEPS]);

    if (requested) {
      try {
        steps = await health.getTotalStepsInInterval(midnight, now);
      } catch (error) {
        print("Caught exception in getTotalStepsInInterval: $error");
      }

      print('Total number of steps: $steps');

      setState(() {
        _nofSteps = (steps == null) ? 0 : steps;
        _state = (steps == null) ? AppState.NO_DATA : AppState.STEPS_READY;
      });
    } else {
      print("Authorization not granted - error in authorization");
      setState(() => _state = AppState.DATA_NOT_FETCHED);
    }
  }
```

Then I am calling this function with await and I also have inserted the correct permission in all Android Manifest files:

Also I set up an OAuth2 Client ID for the project and added my google account as a test user.

BUT THE FUNCTION SETS THE VARIABLE STEPS ALWAYS TO NULL? The boolean variable "requested" is true, so it seems like the actual connection is working?

I am really disappointed by myself guys and I really need help - THANK YOU!

I tried adding the correct android permissions, asking for permissions explicitly, different time intervalls but nothing worked for me, I always got a null value back.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Adding a Google login with specified scope helped. I first log the user in with the code:

```
class LoginController extends GetxController {
  final _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read"]);
  var googleAccount = Rx<GoogleSignInAccount?>(null);

  login() async {
    googleAccount.value = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
  }
}
```

I then retrieve the data using code:

```dart
  getSteps() async {
    await Permission.activityRecognition.request();

    HealthFactory health = HealthFactory();

    // define the types to get
    var types = [
      HealthDataType.STEPS,
    ];

    // requesting access to the data types before reading them
    bool requested = await health.requestAuthorization(types);

    var now = DateTime.now();
    var steps = await health.getTotalStepsInInterval(now.subtract(Duration(days: 1)), now);
  }
```